# A necessary condition of Hausdorff-Young inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

If the inequality $||\{a_n\}||_{L_q}\le A||f||_{L_p}$ holds, with $a_n=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta$, then the sum of $\frac1q$ and $\frac1p$ must be less than 1. It is an exercise of functional analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, in chapter 2. I have no idea where I should start.

Comment: You can perform a dimensional analysis, i.e. define $f_\lambda(x)=f(\lambda x)$, for example, where $\lambda$ is some positive constant. Substitute this $f_\lambda(x)$ into the inequality, together with the assumption that the inequality is true should give you the desired condition for the exponent.

Comment: If we let $f_{\lambda}(x)=f(\lambda x), x\in[0,\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}]$, then we have $a_n^{\lambda}=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}}f_{\lambda}(x) e^{-in \lambda x}dx=a_n$ and $||f_{\lambda}||_{L_p}=(\frac{1}{\lambda})^{\frac1p}||f||_{L_p}$. As a result, we have $||a_n||_{L_q}\le A(\frac1{\lambda})^{\frac1p}||f||_{L_p}$. But I can't get anything further.

Comment: $a_n\neq a_n^{\lambda}$, otherwise things screw up, what happens when you take the Fourier transform of the dilation of a function?

Comment: There is a hint after the problem. It says that let $D_N(\theta)=\sum_{|n|\le N}e^{in\theta}$ be the Dirichlet kernel , then $||D_N||_{L_p}=O(N^{1-\frac1p})$ if $p>1$ and $||D_N||_{L^1}=O(\log N)$. But I don't konw how to use it.

Comment: Hmmmm I have no clue about the hint either. Also I believe that $1/p+1/q$ has to be equal to 1, are you sure about your question ? :O

Comment: The problem is the domain will change when we do the dilation. If it were $\mathbb{R}$, then $ \hat{f}_{\lambda}(\xi)=\frac1{\lambda}\hat{f}(\frac{\xi}{\lambda})$.

Comment: I'm aware of that but everything should still scale down nicely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff%E2%80%93Young_inequality

Comment: I think the question is right. It is an exercise from the book I mentioned.

Comment: I have some problem of following the link. Some part of the Wiki is forbidden in my country. What does it say?

Comment: It basically says that the above inequality is true for $1/p+1/q=1$, $p\in (1,2)$. Actually, he had $(\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|^p dt)^{1/p}$ instead. Hmm, let's hope someone post a solution soon !

Comment: @zzy: The hint you posted pretty much solves the problem. Assume $p>1$ first. Plug $f=D_N$ into your target inequality and note that the left hand side behaves like $n^{1/q}$. The hint gives you the norm of the right hand side. Conclude that the resulting inequality can only hold for $1/p +1/q\leq 1$. For $p=1$, a similar argument works, since the log grows slower than any power of $N$

Comment: @  PhoemueX : Thank you very much! I thought in the left hand of the inequality was the norm of the convolution $f*D_N$ and not aware that plugging $f=D_N$ gives the proof.